# Too many RDS connections while load testing http server on AWS Lambda with RDS proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, webserver, amazon-rds, serverless

### Introduction

I am hosting a web server implemented by `gorilla/mux` which expose API endpoints for users to access the database.

I put the server in a AWS Lambda function and use API Gateway to send Lambda proxy requests to the server. The request flow is:

- API Gateway -> (API Gateway Lambda proxy integration) -> Lambda function -> RDS proxy -> RDS instance

### The server code

```golang
import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-go-api-proxy/core"
    "github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-go-api-proxy/gorillamux"
)

var (
    muxLambda *gorillamux.GorillaMuxAdapter
    router = mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    // Register handler functions
)

func init() {
    muxLambda = gorillamux.New(router)
}

func LambdaHandler(
    ctx context.Context,
    req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest,
) (*core.SwitchableAPIGatewayResponse, error) {
    response, err := muxLambda.ProxyWithContext(ctx, *core.NewSwitchableAPIGatewayRequestV1(&req))
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Proxy encountered an error: %s", err.Error()))
    }
    return response, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(LambdaHandler)
}
```

- I open the connection to database via:

```golang
import "database/sql"
database, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
```

### Problem

While testing the load performance of this server (`siege -c 250 -d 0.5 -r 10 'http://<api url>/`),
I encountered so many connections to the RDS instance (around 400 connections in the AWS console) and the Lambda function returned timeout (30 sec) for almost all transactions.
If I lower the number of process, the response from the server works as expected.

**What are the possible things that cause this?**

From my search, I found that maybe it is due to:

- For each request, a new Lambda instance starts and opens a new database connection to the RDS proxy. With too many connections already there, somehow the Lambda waits and return timeout after 30 seconds.

This might be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177554/how-should-i-manage-postgres-database-handles-in-a-serverless-environment), but I think RDS proxy can handle connection pool for me? Or am I overloading the RDS proxy?

If the cause is overloading, what configuration can I do in the AWS setup?
Scaling up the RDS instances? Or Increase `max_connections` setting as mentioned in this [article](https://www.jeremydaly.com/manage-rds-connections-aws-lambda/)?

Or simply change the code structure as mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688990/flask-web-application-deployment-via-aws-lambda) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177554/how-should-i-manage-postgres-database-handles-in-a-serverless-environment)?

Thanks for reading this far. Any feedback is appreciated.

#### Updated: The connection metrics of RDS and RDS proxy

- [DB connection of the RDS instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRiMq.png)
- [CloudWatch metrics of RDS proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq6vm.png)

Comment: You should look at the connection metrics of both the RDS instance and RDS proxy to see where the issue is.

Comment: @MarkB I have added some connection metrics, it seems the connection spiked during the load testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason that Lambda timeout might due to the fact of too many RDS connections. So the RDS proxy queues or throttles incoming connections from the Lambda ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy.html)).

The root cause was because of too many SQL queries from the API server sending to the RDS, which holds up the connections.
In my case, the query includes 2 steps:

1. Getting a list of id
2. Sends a query for each id such as:

```sql
select row from table where id = 1;
```

In this setting, if there are 200 id in the list, then the API server will send 200 + 1 queries in total, which holds up the connection.

#### Solution

- I modified the API server to send a single query like:

```sql
select row from table where id in (1, 2, 3, ....);
```

- Close the rows from `Db.Query` (from `database/sql`) calls to avoid connection leak:

```golang
rows, err := Db.Query(query, params)
defer rows.Close()
```

In summary, this was due to poor understanding of the `database/sql` go package and SQL. Hopefully this helps those who comes across this.

Answer (score 0):

Increase value of `max_connections` is not best practice.
I think, the better way to use Lambda function [init phase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html#runtimes-lifecycle-ib) to pre-configure RDS connection. This connection will be reused by several lambda functions. This solution decreases number of connections to RDS database.
There are good [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html#vpc-rds-deployment-pkg) how to do this.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary while using RDS Proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was hoping RDS proxy can handle the connections for me.
Do you suggest using configuration like `connect_timeout=5` from the example to limit the RDS connection time?